# Adding Photo Frame To Camera Image on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working to create a view in my app that will allow you to take a picture, and then will automatically draw a frame around that image.  The issue I am facing is that there is some blank space around the top and sides when I do this.  Here is my code:

UPDATE:  If I run this in a 6S, you get image shown below.  If in 6S Plus, you get the final image.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *takePhoto = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Take Picture" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(takingPhoto)];
    UIBarButtonItem *savePhoto = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveIt)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[takePhoto, savePhoto];

}

- (void)takingPhoto{

    ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.delegate = self;
    ipc.allowsEditing = YES;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else
    {
        ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:NULL];    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    self.imgView.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self applyFilter];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)applyFilter {
    NSLog(@"Running");

    UIImage *borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_8055.PNG"];

    NSData *dataFromImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgView.image, 1);

    CIImage *beginImage= [CIImage imageWithData:dataFromImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *border =[CIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(borderImage)];

    CIFilter *filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];  //@"CISoftLightBlendMode"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:border forKey:@"inputImage"];

    [filter setValue:beginImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

    self.imgView.image = newImg;

}
```

In the simulator, it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I look in saved photos after I have saved it, it looks like this:

[image]

Why does it have the white space on top and right side?

Here is the aforementioned 6S Plus image:

[image]

Comment: Probably because the border and the image itself do not have the same size? Probably the border is a bit bigger than the image itself?

Comment: @fishinear Perhaps, but shouldn't it automatically scale to fill?  The frame image is 2732 x 2048 and the image taken I suppose is what the camera takes it at.  In the xib I have AutoLayout set and have constraints for the ImageView for fixed width and height at 400 x 300

Comment: Don't know the details, but I would not expect CIFilter to do automatic resizing if you don't tell it to. It probably takes the largest combined rectangle of both sizes as the size of the output image. You can clearly see in the 6S Plus image that the border is not resized.

Comment: For the `UIImageView` to show the full image, you need to set its `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: @fishinear Ok.  I made the changes in my code to match the size of the frame's image, and it works, but with one small caveat.  Though everything is on a transparent background and PNG, all the music notes for the frame have pixelated white areas surrounding them.

Comment: You might want to ask a new question for that (with a clear picture of how it looks like), but I suspect that comes from how the border image was created. Check in a photo editor against a black background whether the white pixelation is already present in the border image.